# command is not executed in a controller

Tags: symfony

I would like to run a command via a controller. My command run normaly in cli (tests are done)
My controller call the command and I got immediately

```
 [OK] success
```

from the command return but tests did not run.

my controller
`

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controller\Api;

use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;


class UnitTestController extends AbstractController
{
    private $kernel;

    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
    }
    #[Route('/unit_tests', name: 'unit_test', methods: 'GET')]
    public function unitTest(): Response
    {
        $application = new Application($this->kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);

        $input = new ArrayInput([
            'command' => 'mapi:unitTests',
        ]);
        $output = new BufferedOutput();
        $application->run($input, $output);

        // return the output, don't use if you used NullOutput()
        $content = $output->fetch();
        dd($content);

    }
}
```

`

and my command
`

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Attribute\AsCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\ClientExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\DecodingExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\RedirectionExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\ServerExceptionInterface;

#[AsCommand(
    name: 'mapi:unitTests',
    description: 'lancement des tests unitaires',
)]
class unitTestCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * @param InputInterface $input
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     * @return int
     * @throws ClientExceptionInterface
     * @throws DecodingExceptionInterface
     * @throws RedirectionExceptionInterface
     * @throws ServerExceptionInterface
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
        $process = Process::fromShellCommandline('php vendor/bin/phpunit');
        $process->run();
        $io->success('success');

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

edit: no error, unit tests from command are not executed. when I run the command from the cli, everything is ok
`

Comment: What are the class names (and interfaces) and what is the full error message?

Comment: why do you want todo this? was is your use case? using a symfony command to execute phpunit in itself seems off. then calling this command in a controller - there is just no point in my mind to make sense of this.

Comment: My goal is to run unittest from a controller to get .phpunit.result.cache. In a controller unitest aren't run neither with Process()
PS: I use docker

Comment: As a first step - get the output of the command, that will give you a hint. In regards to the error - I'm suspecting that the web version php cannot run shell commands. I think it needs some permissions to do it, but in general that is no so good idea.